# pandas string replace TypeError - replace words using pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am using Python 3.7 and have a large data frame that includes a column of addresses, like so:

```
c = ['420 rodeo drive', '22 alaska avenue', '919 franklin boulevard', '39 emblem alley', '67 fair way']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(c, columns = ["address"])
```

There is also a dataframe of address abbrevations and their usps version.  An example:

```
x = ['avenue', 'drive', 'boulevard', 'alley', 'way']
y = ['aly', 'dr', 'blvd', 'ave', 'way']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x,y)), columns = ['common_abbrev', 'usps_abbrev'], dtype = "str")
```

What I would like to do is as follows:

1. Search `df1['address']` for occurrences of words in `df2['common_abbrev']` and replace with `df2['usps_abbrev']`.
2. Return the transformed `df1`.

To this end I have tried in a few ways what appears to be the canonical strategy of `df.str.replace()` like so:

```
df1["address"] = df1["address"].str.replace(df2["common_abbrev"], df2["usps_abbrev"])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
`TypeError: repl must be a string or callable`.
```

My question is:

1. Since I've already given the `dtype` for `df2`, why am I receiving the error?
2. How can I produce my desired result of:

   ```
            address
   0       420 rodeo dr
   1      22 alaska ave
   2  919 franklin blvd
   3      39 emblem aly
   4        67 fair way
   ```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `dict` using [`zip`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip). Then use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
In [703]: x = ['avenue', 'drive', 'boulevard', 'alley', 'way']
     ...: y = ['aly', 'dr', 'blvd', 'ave', 'way']

In [686]: d = dict(zip(x, y))

In [691]: df1.address = df1.address.replace(d, regex=True)

In [692]: df1
Out[692]: 
             address
0       420 rodeo dr
1      22 alaska aly
2  919 franklin blvd
3      39 emblem ave
4        67 fair way
```

Comment: `d = dict(zip(x, y))` might be better

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yes, updated my answer. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @MayankPorwal thanks this is clean and intuitive.

Comment: @MayankPorwal one more question:  what is it about `dict` that converts my datatype to strings?

Comment: Also, some of the 'ave' replacements are adding an 'e' to the new string, so 'avenue' becomes 'avee' or 'aveee' instead of 'ave'.  Is there a reason why?